# Thumbnail video player in PHP

Tags: php

I have to display video files as in thumbnail form. How can I do that. any body can help me.

Answer (score 6):

There's some info here on creating a thumbnail of a video using ffmpeg, hopefully this will set you in the right direction
http://blog.amnuts.com/2007/06/22/create-a-random-thumbnail-of-a-video-file/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want but i believe you can have few frames cut off from your video file to create a gif. Then you can use this gif image as a thumbnail with a play button overlayed