# FFMpeg - Creating Thumbnail for Video file

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am new to php. I have installed ffmpeg in my local iis.. Is it possible to generate a thumbnail image for a flv file.? Please help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thumbnail video player in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913172/thumbnail-video-player-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate preview image from Video file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043007/generate-preview-image-from-video-file)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
$ffmpeg = 'ffmpeg.exe';

//video dir
$video = 'video.flv';

//where to save the image
$image = 'image.jpg';

//time to take screenshot at
$interval = 5;

//screenshot size
$size = '320x240';

//ffmpeg command
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $interval -f mjpeg -t 1 -r 1 -y -s $size $image 2>&1";       
$return = `$cmd`;
```

An explanation of the command options:

**-i *filename*** (the source video's file path)
**-deinterlace** (converts interlaced video to non-interlaced form)
**-an** (audio recording is disabled; we don't need it for thumbnails)
**-ss *position*** (input video is decoded and dumped until the timestamp reaches *position*, our thumbnail's position in seconds)
**-f *output file format***
**-t *duration*** (the output file stops writing after *duration* seconds)
**-r *fps*** (sets the frame rate to write at; *fps* is expressed in Hertz (1/seconds); we use 1 so that we grab only one frame)
**-y** (overwrites the output file if it already exists)
**-s** widthxheight (size of the frame in pixels)

Comment: Hint: Put the infile **-i** value after **--ss** to considerably speed up the process.

Answer (score 2):

Following script ic created using PHP FFMPEG Library . You can grab the video information and thumbnail using the given functions

```
<?php

class PHP_FFMPEG
{

function getVideoInformation($videoPath)
{
$movie = new ffmpeg_movie($videoPath,false);

$this->videoDuration = $movie->getDuration();
$this->frameCount = $movie->getFrameCount();
$this->frameRate = $movie->getFrameRate();
$this->videoTitle = $movie->getTitle();
$this->author = $movie->getAuthor() ;
$this->copyright = $movie->getCopyright();
$this->frameHeight = $movie->getFrameHeight();
$this->frameWidth = $movie->getFrameWidth();
$this->pixelFormat = $movie->getPixelFormat();
$this->bitRate = $movie->getVideoBitRate();
$this->videoCodec = $movie->getVideoCodec();
$this->audioCodec = $movie->getAudioCodec();
$this->hasAudio = $movie->hasAudio();
$this->audSampleRate = $movie->getAudioSampleRate();
$this->audBitRate = $movie->getAudioBitRate();


}


function getAudioInformation($videoPath)
{
$movie = new ffmpeg_movie($videoPath,false);

$this->audioDuration = $movie->getDuration();
$this->frameCount = $movie->getFrameCount();
$this->frameRate = $movie->getFrameRate();
$this->audioTitle = $movie->getTitle();
$this->author = $movie->getAuthor() ;
$this->copyright = $movie->getCopyright();
$this->artist = $movie->getArtist();
$this->track = $movie->getTrackNumber();
$this->bitRate = $movie->getBitRate();
$this->audioChannels = $movie->getAudioChannels();
$this->audioCodec = $movie->getAudioCodec();
$this->audSampleRate = $movie->getAudioSampleRate();
$this->audBitRate = $movie->getAudioBitRate();

}

function getThumbImage($videoPath)
{
$movie = new ffmpeg_movie($videoPath,false);
$this->videoDuration = $movie->getDuration();
$this->frameCount = $movie->getFrameCount();
$this->frameRate = $movie->getFrameRate();
$this->videoTitle = $movie->getTitle();
$this->author = $movie->getAuthor() ;
$this->copyright = $movie->getCopyright();
$this->frameHeight = $movie->getFrameHeight();
$this->frameWidth = $movie->getFrameWidth();

$capPos = ceil($this->frameCount/4);

if($this->frameWidth>120)
{
$cropWidth = ceil(($this->frameWidth-120)/2);
}
else
{
$cropWidth =0;
}
if($this->frameHeight>90)
{
$cropHeight = ceil(($this->frameHeight-90)/2);
}
else
{
$cropHeight = 0;
}
if($cropWidth%2!=0)
{
$cropWidth = $cropWidth-1;
}
if($cropHeight%2!=0)
{
$cropHeight = $cropHeight-1;
}

$frameObject = $movie->getFrame($capPos);


if($frameObject)
{
$imageName = "tmb_vid_"1212.jpg";
$tmbPath = "/home/home_Dir/public_html/uploads/thumb/".$imageName;
$frameObject->resize(120,90,0,0,0,0);
imagejpeg($frameObject->toGDImage(),$tmbPath);
}
else
{
$imageName="";
}


return $imageName;

}






}




?>
```

Function

```
getThumbImage($videoPath); //pass path to video file //
```

will create number of thumbnails in folder specified in the function .
You can alter the code according to your requirement . This works if you installed ffmpeg and php ffmpeg library .

Refer this link
http://tecserver.blogspot.in/2009/07/ffmpeg-video-conversion-tool.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php

$W = intval($_GET['W']);
 $H = intval($_GET['H']);
$pic = ''.htmlspecialchars($_GET['file']).''; 
$name = 'wapadmin/'.str_replace('/','--',$pic).'.gif';
$location = 'http://'.str_replace(array('\\','//'),array('/','/'),    $_SERVER                 [ 'HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/'.$name);

 if(file_exists($name)){
header('Location: '.$location, true, 301);
 exit;
}

$mov = new ffmpeg_movie($pic, false);
$wn = $mov->GetFrameWidth();
$hn = $mov->GetFrameHeight();


$frame = $mov->getFrame(480);

$gd = $frame->toGDImage();

 if(!$W and !$H){
  $a = "131*79";
  $size = explode('*',$a);
 $W = round(intval($size[0])); 
 $H = round(intval($size[1])); 
  }


 $new = imageCreateTrueColor($W, $H);
 imageCopyResampled($new, $gd, 0, 0, 0, 0, $W, $H, $wn, $hn);
 imageGif($new, $name, 100);

  header('Location: '.$location, true, 301);
  ?>
```

Comment: this code is not compelete. you should add  $mov = new ffmpeg_movie('./Wildlife.wmv'); instead of "$mov = new ffmpeg_movie($pic, false);" that it mean you are using "Wildlife.wmv" exactly on your root drectory close to the .php file.
and also you should change "imageGif($new, $name, 100);" to "imageGif($new, "yourname.gif", 100);"
it will create a file named "yourname.gif" close to your php file.
hope help someone

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify a time of 1. The ffmpeg api provides a format of image2 and the ability to pass -vframes 1.

```
$time = 3;
$infile = 'in.mp4';
$thumbnail = 'my_thumbnail.png';

$cmd = sprintf(
    'ffmpeg -i %s -ss %s -f image2 -vframes 1 %s',
    $infile, $time, $thumbnail
); 

exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can run ffmpeg from PHP using the [right parameters](http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/29/creating-video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg/).

Using ffmpeg-php, you can use $movie->getFrame() to obtain a frame, and $frame->toGDImage() to get a [GD image](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Comment: How to use $movie->getFrame().?