# How to get thmbnail from video url?

Tags: php, html, html5-video

I need to get image thumbnail from video url. PHP or JQUERY

http://example.com/video/847363.mp4 im using html5 player but i want show the thumbnail.

if i give a video url it will turn to image. like [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/blog/video_transcoding_resizing_cropping_and_manipulating_made_easy)

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/w_300,h_300,c_fill,r_max,e_sharpen,so_15p/l_cloudinary_icon,w_0.5,fl_relative,o_40,g_north/funny_dog.jpg
```

Comment: Why do you need the thumbnail when video load it shows the preview

Comment: yes but i need to show the list of thumbnails then click thumbnail to go to the video page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FFMpeg - Creating Thumbnail for Video file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095918/ffmpeg-creating-thumbnail-for-video-file)

Comment: but ffmpeg only working on dedicated server not in shared hosting.

Comment: I guess for this type of operations you can't use shared server