# How to create a thumbnail for video file

Tags: php, ffmpeg-php

I have been working on php for a while and i stuck at the point where i need to create thumbnail for video file using ffmpeg.

I looked up for same, but did not get any solution yet.

I found so many solutions to create a thumbnail from video file, but i want to create a thumbnail for video file.

EX. i will upload video file and image file and then this image file will be set as a thumbnail for a video.

Any solution .... if possible using ffmpeg then it would be great

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there any way, we can save the thumbnail poster in video or we need to display thumbnail using html side only?

Comment: duplicated.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095918/ffmpeg-creating-thumbnail-for-video-file

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas  No,i already checked that post, it is for get the thumbnail from video, but i want to create thumbnail poster for video file. it's different.

Comment: Do you want to set you uploaded image as thumbnail for some specific service? Can you write where are you plaining to use it?

Otherwise

Thumbnail doesn't stored in video. 
Thumbnail of video is one random frame or frame from specific moment selected by service.  (5th second, etc.)

Comment: Actually i am working on video tutorials where i upload videos, but i want to show custom thumbnail image on video cover instead of the inside video thumbnail of 5 seconds as you said.

Comment: i am able to do it with HTML <video></video> , but i want to know if it is possible to save this thumbnail in video using ffmpeg or any other tool