# Is there any way of extracting thumbnail(s) from a video using php

Tags: php, thumbnails

Is there anyway of extracting frame(s) from a video as thumbnail(s) for the video using php

Comment: Videos don't have thumbnails, they have frames. Probably could use ffmpeg for this. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095918/ffmpeg-creating-thumbnail-for-video-file) should help you about what you want